# How to check if the file is still being copied in cpp using windows API?

Tags: c++, file, winapi

In my current project, we had a requirement to check if the file is still copying.

We have already developed a library which will give us OS notification like file_added , file_removed , file_modified, file_renamed on a particular folder along with the corresponding file path.

The problem here is that, lets say if you add 1 GB file, it is giving multiple notification such as file_added , file_modified, file_modified as the file is being copied.

Now i decided to surpass these notifications by checking if the file is copying or not. Based on that i will ignore events.

I have written below function in c++ which tells if the file is being copied or not which takes file path as input.
Details:- Basically it uses windows API "CreateFile" to get file handle. If we are not able acquire handle then it is determined as file is being copied.

Problem :- For some larger files like 2 GB with .rar & .exe format, this not working. Can you please advice me is this is right approach or not? If not appreciate other approaches.

```
bool isFileBeingCopied(const boost::filesystem::path &filePath)
{
     //Log(INFO, "Checking if the given file is being copied or not for the file [%s]",filePath.string().c_str());
     HANDLE hFile = ::CreateFile(filePath.c_str(), GENERIC_READ, 0, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, NULL);
     DWORD dwLastError = GetLastError();

     if(hFile == NULL && hFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
     {
          Log(INFO, "Gained invalid handle on the file - hence determining it, as being copied file [%s]",filePath.string().c_str());
          return true;
     }
     else
     {
          if(dwLastError == ERROR_SUCCESS )
          {
                CloseHandle(hFile);
                Log(INFO, "Able to gain the handle on the file - hence determining it, as copied file [%s]",filePath.string().c_str());
                return false;
          }
          else
          {
              Log(INFO, "Not able to gain the handle for the file - hence determining it, as being copied file [%s]",filePath.string().c_str());
              return true;
          }
     }               
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Unless you are copying the file yourself,there is no way to determine the file's copy state externally. You will likely have to use a timer to detect when the file modified events stop being sent to you.

Comment: I think in this way i cant distinguish if it is manual edit by user or file copy

Comment: See if creating a [copy hook handler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144063.aspx) will work for your needs.

Answer (score 1):

using [boost filesystem](http://www.boost.org/libs/filesystem) libs, we can find out whether the file is getting copied or not. Basically boost::filesystem::fstream class opens the file for the I/O operations. When the file is currently getting copied, boost lib cannot open the file and is_open() method will return false. So, in this case, we can safely assume that file is currently getting copied. If the file is broken or damaged also, we end up being in this situation.

In all the other cases, is_open() returns true and we can consider as file copy is done(in this use case)
Hope this code helps.

```
boost::filesystem::fstream fileStream(filePath, std::ios_base::in | std::ios_base::binary);

if(fileStream.is_open())
{
    //We could open the file, so file is good
    //So, file is not getting copied.
}
else
{
    //Wait, the file is currently getting copied. 
}
```

EDIT: Added more explanation

Answer (score 0):

If the file has been previously open (and still is) with `dwShareMode` = 0, IOW, in an exclusive access mode, you won't be able to open it again until it closes, irrespective of whether the file is being copied (=written to) or not, and so your function's return value of `true` cannot be relied upon.

Note that if `CreateFile()` succeeds, you call `CloseHandle()` and return `false`. Immediately after this the file can get opened for writing by another process, and, again, the returned value of `false` cannot be relied upon because of the possibility of this race condition. If you want to prevent it, you must not close the handle until you no longer interested in having exclusive access to the file.

So, this is clearly not the right way to determine precisely whether a file is being copied (=written to) or not. And it appears as a meaningless thing to do.

It seems to me that you're trying to solve the wrong problem here. What's the real problem in whose context you have decided to check if a file is being copied (=written to) or not? If you tell us that, we might be able to help with that real problem.

Comment: It is not just exclusive access that can cause `CreateFile()` to fail. As long as the file is not open for read sharing, since this code is asking for it, then it will fail.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Right, files previously opened with `FILE_SHARE_WRITE` will cause `CreateFile()` to fail in `isFileBeingCopied()`.

Comment: More accurately, files not opened with `FILE_SHARE_READ`.

Comment: Thanks for your time. Here is the context. Once i determine that file is copied it will be uploaded to server. Just think of dropbox service. The reason i close handle is to let users to edit the file as they wish

Comment: Bit more context, if i start uploading file upon OS notification i  am ending up with uploading multiple versions of single file with improper sizes as it is still being copied.

Comment: Can you set it up to copy the file using a temporary filename, then rename the file at the end? That way you can ignore the temp filenames. Another option would be to create a custom shell namespace extension for the user to copy into. Then you have more control over the files and copy operations.